# Symfony2 Form entity query_builder inner method access options

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am building a form with a entity type field that should use a query builder. To create the query builder I need to use the options passed to the form. How can I do this?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
  $builder->add(
    'groups',
    'entity',
    array(
      'required' => true,
      'class' => 'CompanyCoreBundle:Group',
      'multiple' => true,
      'label' => 'Groups',
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        // need the $options parameter of buildForm here!
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do this by using the `use` statement, something like this:**

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                        // you can now use your $options here
                        //...define $query

                        return $query;
                    },
```